# jquery carousel with pagination

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

Can anyone show me carousel with pagination and "play" button, with customizable css and infinity numeric pagination(max 6)?

Pagination such:

```
  < 1 2 3 ... 90 >
```

Comment: What is the "..." button supposed to do? I find it a bit counter-intuitive on a carousel.

Comment: this show what many slides in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ - i think this solves your problem mostly. after that, just tune it up